# Cakephp: Multiple files upload field sets to required automatically

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Simple problem, but can't find my solution. I have a gallery upload field with multiple files like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.gallery.', array(
    'label' => __('Gallery'),
    'type' => 'file',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
));
```

And i got the validation rules like this:

```
'gallery' => array(
    'fileSize' => array(
        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
        'message' => 'Image must be less than 1MB',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'last' => false,
    ),
    'extension' => array(
        'rule' => array('extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')),
        'message' => 'Invalid image',
    ),
),
```

If i put a single file upload field, then it is not required. When i set it to multiple, it is required and I don't want it to be. How do i do this?

**EDIT:**

The catch was setting `'required' => false` in the input field options, in the .ctp file:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.gallery.', array(
    'label' => __('Gallery'),
    'type' => 'file',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'required' => false,
));
```

The validation rules in the model remained the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `'novalidate'` to your options array in `$this->Form->create();`. This disables HTML5 validation.

I expect that will work but if not try adding `'required' => false` to your validation rules (goes by field not rule so you only need it in one of the rules not both)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will check it at Monday, my project is at work :). I think I already tried with the required parameter and it didn't work. And if I add `'novalidate'` to the options, wouldn't that cause it to skip my filesize and extension validations?

Comment: Okay, I got it working, the solution was 'required' => false in the input field options (not validation rules in the model). I will edit my post now.

Comment: I tried `'novalidate'` and it was still marked as a required field. The problem was not in the Model validation settings, but in the view, that is why `'required' => false` in the input field worked I guess.
Btw, I didn't know what `'novalidate'` does, thanks for that.